# GCS Fuse storage mount issue with apache web server as document root

Tags: apache, google-cloud-storage, gcsfuse

I'm Trying to mount google cloud storage using fuse tool as apache doucment root for my web server. cloud storage bucket successfully mounted in my apache document root  but when i access any file like index.html it showing 403 Forbidden. 
I also tried with mount option of uid n gid of apache but still facing same problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the exactly same issue. I happened resolve it by adding option `-o allow_other`. Hope it is also helpful for you. Good luck.

Comment: Lifesaver - much appreciated